# Recursively Create a Menu using two Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recursion, razor

I'm having trouble making a dynamic menu using ASP.NET MVC where the menu is organized according to your `Groups` in Active Directory. To cut through useless details, I have retrieved two lists: one gives me all the `folders` of the menu, the other gives me all the `files`. How would one go about recursively creating the menu, knowing that `folders` can have `subfolders`, and `subsubfolders` and so on? In my project they are called I have two models `DocumentModel` and `CategoryModel` as follows :

```
//Files
public class DocumentModel
{
    public long iDDocument { get; set; }
    public long iDCategory { get; set; }
    public string docName { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
//Folders
public class CategoryModel
{
    public long iDCategory { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public int iDParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

I then pass them to my view using a bigger model:

```
public class CatDocViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> catModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DocumentModel> docModel { get; set; }
}
```

So my idea is to make a recursive method in a partial view. Using Razor `helpers` I can make a recursive method, but I'm having a hard time with these kinds of methods.

Another problem arising is that I use `IEnumerable` so I have to loop through them, will that be too costly for the algorithm since I will recurse and loop again etc ...? But I also cannot make it without recursion since the depth of folders is unknown, so I have to recurse until I hit the end and then roll back up. But How?

I don't think anyone can make the algorithm but if you had some directions to point me in so  I can maybe delve into recursivity and understand how to do it?

**EDIT** As suggested in the marked answer, here is what I would do to then build then `Child` lists:

```
    public List<CategoryModel> getDocumentChilren(List<CategoryModel> categories, List<DocumentModel> documents)
    {
        foreach(var cat in categories)
        {
            if (cat.idParentCategory == 0)
                continue;
            foreach(var nextCat in categories)
            {
                if (nextCat.idParentCategory == cat.idParentCategory && nextCat.idCategory != cat.idCategory)
                    cat.childCategories.Add(nextCat);
            }
            foreach (var nextDoc in documents)
            {
                if (nextDoc.idCategory == cat.idCategory)
                    cat.childDocuments.Add(nextDoc);
            }
        }
        return categories;
    }
```

This is O(n^2) I believe so is it ok? If I were to make an estimation, I'd have about 20 entries per loop, so that wouldn't be too greedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would organize the folders in a class more suitable for a tree structure like this:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public long iDCategory { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryModel> ChildCategories {get;set;}
    public List<DocumentModel> ChildDocuments {get;set;}
}
```

Then, instead of using `CatDocViewModel` , you could use `List<CategoryModel>` as the view model for the menu.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a really good idea, I'm marking as accepted. So that supposes I have to first find the children of every document / category? I was also thinking I can maybe use a linked list in order to use recursion (in that way I do not use for loop which would probably make some execution errors).

Comment: I'm not sure how efficient that is. It really depends on the size of your collections.There are methods though to convert a List to a Tree structure. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947831/c-sharp-algorithm-for-generating-hierarchy

Comment: Running it takes 1.8s but sometimes just 350ms, I'm guessing it has to do with some compilation stuff? (am looking this up right now). I think, I'd have a maximum of 30*30 results to compare. so that'd be 900 operations, which is ok I think? Thanks for link I'll check it out